# Geocoding in Lightswitch

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, openstreetmap, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am writing an application for a delivery company. I have an address entity that I would like to geocode addresses and save the lat and longs in sql servers for routing. I am a newbie and I don't understand how to use accomplish this. I would like to use openstreetmaps in my vb lightswitch application and I need someone to explain to me step by step what I need to do to accomplish this. I have been doing research on geocoding all day today and I cannot find the resources I need to get started. There is alot of information out there, by nothing that I have found is step by step to do this. I don't know how to generate an xml file with the data to use REST or SOAP. When I say step by step, I mean literally. I am a noob at all of this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Boy, this is a very complex question.
First of all, what are your needs?

1. Geocode your address to Long/Lat
2. Storing Long/Lat per address
3. Getting routes between two addresses (?)
4. Store Routes between two addresses (?)

### Geocode your address to Long/Lat

When working with OpenStreetmap data (what I haven't done for quite a while) I prefer the [Mapquest Geocode API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/). But if you want to set up you own Server, or don't want to use Mapquest you should implement Nominatim ([MQ](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/), [OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)). If you can handle HTTP APIs and JSON you should be fine with the service pretty fast.

### Storing Long/Lat per address

This is tricky. As far as i know it's not possible to store geospacial information with LS. I would try to have two string fields in LS with the serialisation of Long/lat. I would also suggest to use SQL 2012, because it has a richer geospacial function set. Next I would try to set a trigger in the SQL server to store a serialised geo-point as [SQL geography point](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx). Depending on what you are doing you might want to set a trigger for serialising a SQL geography point, when it's changed. This way you are able to easily access all the cool [SQL Server geography stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933811.aspx).

### Getting/Storing routes between two addresses

I'm not sure if you need more information on that topic, so i'll not dig in very deep. With mapquest you can use the [Directions Service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/). I don't know a good Directions service for OSM, but this information may be outdated. If you stay to the service results it shoudn't be a problem to store routes, given the information about Storing Long/Lat per address.

I hope this helps!